# Pulling the recipient scores from an external API using automation just before sending in SFMC?

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, bulk-api, external-services

I am considering pulling an audience in Marketing Cloud in real-time from an external (REST) API, directly before a send-out.

I know that this is technically possible to pull out using a script activity and saving the information in a data extension.

But I would like to hear your thoughts on whether this is recommended to do. There would be a max of 10 million recipients and it could be done in a bulk as well as one-record-per-call manner.

Comment: It is indeed feasible. However, how do you ensure the pull finishes "directly before a send-out"? Given the number of records, I will recommend you to implement this via an SFTP file upload, a file drop trigger automation, import activity, SQL query and email send activity.

Comment: Include some validity checks in the stuff that lukas has mentioned or you can have some bad results :D

Comment: I agree with the SFTP file upload approach, but there are some hard requirements to pull the audience (SubscriberKeys only) from an external API as close to send-time as possible and then match the data with the profile data stored locally. I will, of course, try to implement the checks and caching, but just wanted to hear from any previous experience whether the platform can handle such load.